# Error when trying to corrupt packets in linux terminal (netem)

Tags: terminal, corruption, tc, packet

The following rule corrupts 5% of the packets by introducing a single bit error at a random offset in the packet:

> sudo tc qdisc change dev ens8 root netem corrupt 5%

But recently it gave me the following error:

> Error: Qdisc not found. To create specify NLM_F_CREATE flag

Could you kindly help me or provide me with some other methods to simulate packet corruption?
I'm trying to simulate packet corruption to see how well my error detection mechanism works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial default *qdisc* set by the kernel with special handle `0:` can't be modified nor referenced. It can only be overridden by a new *qdisc*. Using `change` references the existing *root* *qdisc*, but as this can't be the default kernel's qdisc, that's an error.

So the first time this *netem* *qdisc* is used, the `add` keyword should be used, and that's probably what was done at some point in the past. Then later the `change` keyword can be used to alter some of its parameters (like the corruption percent), since referencing it by the `root` keyword is enough.

As a shortcut `replace` will attempt `change` and if it fails will perform `add` instead.

So in the end this command will work the first and the following times too:

```
sudo tc qdisc replace dev ens8 root netem corrupt 5%
```

To remove this *qdisc* this should be done once (it would fail the 2nd time because that would be again done on the default *qdisc* installed by the kernel which is off-limits):

```
sudo tc qdisc delete dev ens8 root
```

The usage of `add`, `change`, `replace` (which is `change` or else `add`) and `delete` follows a similar pattern among many other *iproute2* commands.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I want to use this method to test the TCP error rate (in detecting faulty packets), but it appears that TCP detects every corruption. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: TCP being provided as a *reliable* service will trigger retransmission of lost packets (IP checksum or TCP checksum causing the corrupted packets to be dropped) so in the end, beside a slowdown (5% might be enough for an important slowdown), the application won't notice nor be able to notice. So I don't understand what you mean. Perhaps that's a case of [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?